# Matching controls in staggered difference-in-differences

Tags: regression, difference-in-difference, matching

I am planning a staggered difference-in-differences analysis examining the impact of a change in health policy at the county level. The policy was implemented at different times in different counties, and in many counties not at all. I have data for all counties in the country, with only a small fraction having ever implemented the policy.

My question concerns choosing the appropriate control counties to include in my analysis. If I were performing a simple diff-in-diff analysis with a treatment enacted in one county only, I would choose the most closely "matched" county for the control and include only those two. However, given that I have a large number of staggered treatment counties which will all be included in the model and which will contribute variable amounts of data, is there still the same importance to find a 1-to-1 matching control for each? Does it make more sense to use the properties I *would* match on as covariates in the model and then include more of my available control data, without worrying about matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection of control groups in a staggered difference-in-differences (DiD) setup is a little more complicated than in a typical DiD technique, particularly when interventions are implemented at different times across units. Building a conventional one-to-one matched control for every treated county may not be practical or the best effective use of your data, given your many treatment counties and different implementation times. Here are a few considerations for selecting control counties in your staggered DiD analysis:

Covariates vs. Matching: It might be more realistic to incorporate all possible control counties and use covariates in the regression model to account for county-to-county variances rather than attempting to match every treatment county to a control county. By using this method, you may take use of the entire set of data and lower the possibility of bias resulting from faulty matching.

Generalised DiD Framework: You can use all available data, without rigorous matching, from treated and untreated counties, in a generalised DiD framework. Time fixed effects would be included in this model to account for common shocks that affect all counties at each time point, and county fixed effects would be included to account for time-invariant variations between counties.

1. Covariates vs. Matching: It might be more realistic to incorporate all possible control counties and use covariates in the regression model to account for county-to-county variances rather than attempting to match every treatment county to a control county. By using this method, you may take use of the entire set of data and lower the possibility of bias resulting from faulty matching.
2. Generalised DiD Framework: You can use all available data, without rigorous matching, from treated and untreated counties, in a generalised DiD framework. Time fixed effects would be included in this model to account for common shocks that affect all counties at each time point, and county fixed effects would be included to account for time-invariant variations between counties.
3. Synthetic Control technique: The synthetic control technique builds a weighted combination of control units that most closely resembles the properties of each treated unit before the treatment, and you can use it to do a robustness check. This approach can be modified for phased implementation, however it can be especially helpful in cases where there are few treated units.
4. The fundamental presumption of DiD analysis is that the treated and control groups would have followed parallel courses in the absence of treatment. Validating this assumption for your staggered design is crucial. One way to do this could be to look at pre-treatment patterns in the outcome variable.
5. Using All Control Data: If you account for the variations between treated and control counties using covariates or fixed effects, adding more control counties without tight matching can improve the accuracy of your results. When you are unsure about the comparability of any particular control unit, this method may be helpful.
6. Variable Treatment Timing: Because the timing of the treatments varies, you must make sure that the control counties are positioned in relation to each treatment group at the right moment. Group-time fixed effects, which enable the treatment impact to change over time and between groups, can be used to achieve this.
7. Approaches to Econometrics for Staggered DiD: The intricacies of staggered DiD designs are tackled by the latest advancements in econometrics. The Callaway and Sant'Anna (2020) approach and Sun and Abraham's (2021) estimator are two techniques that offer approaches for estimating treatment effects that change over time and between groups.

References:

Callaway, B. and Sant’Anna, P., “Difference-in-differences with multiple time periods”. Journal of Econometrics, Forthcoming, December 2020.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304407620303948

Sun, L., & Abraham, S. (2021). Estimating dynamic treatment effects in event studies with heterogeneous treatment effects. Journal of Econometrics, 225(2), 175-199.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S030440762030378X